# RestAssured JsonPath: How to filter json objects from json

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm trying to take an array of objects from json file and i have an issue.

```
path.get("wgcTournaments.items")
```

What path i should use to get all items(item0, item1, item2 ...) in items?

Can you please give me an advice how to do it.

Json example

```
{
  "wgcTournaments": {
    "items": {
      "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
      "item0": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "test": "test",
        "test1": "test1"
      },
      "item1": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "test": "test",
        "test1": "test1"
      },
      "item2": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "test": "test",
        "test1": "test1"
      },
      "item3": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "test": "test",
        "test1": "test1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The best way to filter item from items object but i don't understand how to do it with json path.

Comment: You are trying to get an array of `MyClass` objects but in your JSON you have an object, not an array of objects.

Comment: AntoineB i want to get an array of item0, item1, item2 etc looks like they are an array of objects

Comment: Take a look at the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for my question.

If you want to get item from items you need to use this one json Path

```
path.getObject("wgcTournaments.items*.
find{it.key.startsWith('item')}.value",ItemClass[].class);
```

Note:
it was RestAssured and he uses Gpath more details you can find here 
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_gpath

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deserialize an object into an array of objects. Either your code or your JSON (most likely) is wrong.

If you want to deserialize `items` as an array, your JSON should be the following:

```
{
  "wgcTournaments": {
    "items": [
        {
          "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
          "item0": {},
          "item1": {},
          "item2": {},
          "item3": {}
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if your JSON is correct, you should deserialize your JSON using the following line:

```
path.getObject("wgcTournaments.items", MyClass.class)
```

**EDIT**: After your edit, this seems to be what you want:

If your JSON in correct and you indeed want an array, I assume that each `itemX` is a the key and `{}` the corresponding value. In this case, you have to know that you cannot have an associative array in JSON, you should use a custom solution to deserialize it, because your associative array will be converted into an object.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how i can get all item from items with json path? Maybe something like wgcTournaments.items.findAll {item ...}

Comment: You cannot get it directly. You might be able to declare something like a converter that would handle the data but you'll have to look for how to do it, I'm not very experienced with it.

Comment: Sorry i edited question I need a json path not a way to convert it.

Comment: Then I don't think you can, you can't get a path to an array if your JSON is not an array I believe.